# Kotlin: gradle sync error in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

After adding Kotlin to a module I get the following error when syncing:

```
Error:null cannot be cast to non-null type org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.WrappedVariantData
```

I added the kotlin plugin to this project.  It is an appengine module.  I'm running:
 AS 2.3.2
 gradle 3.4
 kotlin 1.1.2-3

using these plugins:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'
apply plugin: 'idea'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Kotlin are you running? How does your build.gradle looks like in terms of Kotlin dependencies. More info is needed to be able to help.  Just FYI, for AS2.3 you need to use Kotlin 1.1.2-3. Seems 1.1.2-4 only works with AS3.0 Canary.

Comment: updated the questions with kotlin version

Comment: I got this working by removing the 'kotlin-kapt' plugin. Apparently an older version(v1)  of kapt is included in the 'kotlin' plugin.  I have yet to get the new version to work with this setup.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in the kotlin-kapt plugin.  There is a fix in 1.1.3, which is currently in EAP and should be released very soon to stable(June 2017).

More info:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17999#tab=Comments